# Functional derivatives

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I am having trouble with the definition of functional derivatives to see that the following expression is zero.

The expression is:

$$\int{\nabla \left(\frac{\delta F}{\delta B}\times \frac{\delta G}{\delta B} \right)  d^3x}$$

Here $F(B(x))$ and $G(B(x))$ are functionals and $B(x)$ is a 3D vector  field with components $B_x,B_y,B_z$.

Can I say this is zero if B tends to zero when x tends to infinity?

Comment: Thank you Andras